# Edit homepage permission

Tags: home-page-layout

Can anyone help me with this basic. IS it possible to give edit homepage access to particular user without giving system admin profile? if yes, then can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with help of permission sets. You can grant **Customize Application** access in System Permission. But this will give user other permissions as well. Check [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194001&type=1) what other User capabilities will be enabled when 'Customize Application' Profile permission is set.

Comment: Do you know any other workaround for that. because, this customize application is giving so many other permissions as well, which I can't give. So any other way to sort it out. Because My client requirement is, they want to give edit home page option to a user/profile.